# Creating multiple htaccess rewrites

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have a .htaccess file that rewrites `dyhamb.com/episode.php?episode=1` as `dyhamb.com/1`. I would also like another that rewrites `dyhamb.com/blogpost.php?bp=1` as `dyhamb.com/blog/1`.

I have the code set up for the episode rewrite already however when I go to add the blog rewrite I can't seem to get it to work. How would I alter the following to make that possible?

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dyhamb\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://dyhamb.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(0|[1-9]\d{0,2})$ /episode.php?episode=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/blog$ /blogpost.php?blog=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+episode\.php\?episode=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+blogpost\.php\?blog=(\d+) [NC]

RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I don't see any /blog/ rules in your htaccess

Comment: My mistake. I've added them in now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate the 2 and duplicate the set of conditions that you have. The conditions only apply to the immediately following rule:

```
RewriteCond <something>
RewriteCond <something-else>
# those 2 conditions only apply to this rule:
RewriteRule <match> <target>

# This rule has no conditions
RewriteRule <match2> <target2>
```

So you want your htaccess to look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dyhamb\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://dyhamb.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Setup conditions for internal rewrite of episode.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Rewrite for episode.php
RewriteRule ^(0|[1-9]\d{0,2})$ /episode.php?episode=$1 [L,QSA]

# Setup conditions for internal rewrite of blopost.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Rewrite for blogpost.php
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /blogpost.php?blog=$1 [L,QSA]

# External redirect for episodes
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+episode\.php\?episode=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

# External redirect for blog
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+blogpost\.php\?blog=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /blog/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Note that there needed to be some changes to your blog rules. If these rules are going to be in an .htaccess file, the leading slash is stripped off of the URI before the rewrite engine processes it, so the expression `^/blog` needed to be `^blog`, and I added a backreferenced match `(.*)` after the blog since you want to be able to access the ID after it to insert into the `blog=` query string in your target. Also, the external redirect for blog was missing the `/blog/` before the ID.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the suggestion, however it doesn't seem to have worked. When I go to `dyhamb.com/blogpost.php?blog=1` for example the rewrite to `/blog/1` doesn't seem to happen. Not sure why this would be.

Comment: @Ryan It works as intended for me when I copy and paste everything into a blank htaccess file in a vanilla apache's document root: http://i.stack.imgur.com/TUOFT.png

Comment: Okay, so for the blog rewrite, what output are you getting? What I want is `dyhamb.com/blogpost.php?blog=1` to rewrite as `dyhamb.com/blog/1`. Is that what you're getting? I feel like there may be an extra `blog` somewhere in your suggestion that I'm not picking up on.

Comment: @Ryan Look at the left terminal where there is an open connection to the apache server. I am requesting `/blogpost.php?blog=1` and the host as `dyhamb.com` and apache is returning a `301 Moved Permanently` to `http://dyhamb.com/blog/1`

Comment: "**I feel like there may be an extra `blog` somewhere in your suggestion that I'm not picking up on.**" Is the very last rule that you have identical to the one in my post: `RewriteRule ^ /blog/%1? [R=301,L]`?

Comment: Bazinga - this works now. I had missed off the last `/blog/` as you mentioned above.